# Accessing protected mysql names via ASP

Tags: mysql, ms-access, asp-classic, ado

Currently, I've been assisting someone to convert a site using classic ASP, from using MS Access to MySQL(mainly as a bridge until we get time to do a complete rebuild). The current table uses various protected keywords as column names(Datetime, Date, Order, etc). I'm trying to figure out the proper ways to do a few inserts on these columns. The current code is below:

```
Set oRSess = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        oRSess.AddNew
        oRSess.Fields("Order") = CInt(xyz)
        oRSess.Fields("SessionID")
        oRSess.Update
```

Now normally, I'd try to just replace this with a standard SQL insert, but there's lots of code around, that breaks easily. Is there away to add a proper escape character for MySQL to recognize it properly?

Comment: Try escaping column names with back-ticks.

Comment: Changing to oRSess.Fields("`Order`") (with the `) results in the error: "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. "

Comment: I'm not sure that method would actually work with MySQL.  The MyODBC data provider doesn't support the cursor and lock types available in MSJet OLEDB

Comment: I don't use mySQL (hence comment, not answer), but have you tried using square brackets around the, uh, misguided column names?

Comment: Square brackets are not applicable for MySQL, need to use ` around the field names. Ended up just rewriting the code to a standard query instead of the AddNew/Update style